# Make printer wireless using windows share printer for airprint

Tags: printer, hp-laserjet

I have a HP LaserJet printer (wired model). The printer is connected to my Windows 11 machine via a USB cable. My requirement is that iOS devices can print to that printer (I assume AirPrint is the only way). I have installed the latest drivers, shared the printer from properties, installed the Elpamsoft AirPrint installer, and installed the Apple bonjour printer wizard.

Despite all these efforts, my iOS device still cannot find the printer/my computer. Both iOS and Windows devices are connected to the same network.

Thanks in advance. I’m new so I’m not really sure if this is the right place to ask. Please let me know if not.

Thanks again :)

Comment: Check to see if your model supports airpriint. Numerous printers do not.

Comment: @John it doesn’t but i’m assuming that doesn’t matter if i’m sharing it using a computer?

Comment: This approach is targeted specifically at printers that don't support airprint.  Make sure that UDP port 5353 is open in windows fw

Comment: @BlindSpots it was not, i have now enabled it through windows firewall, still no success though.

Comment: Take a look at this  [airprint guide](https://ericdraken.com/airprint-windows-usb-printer/) particularly  ``Registry Tweak for Windows 10+`` The guide includes config for pfsense for Airprint across subnets but you can ignore the parts that aren't relevant. Seems like a good list of steps and reccomedations including the free iPhone lan service Discovery app.  If that helps I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: @BlindSpots i managed to get it working and it is discovered in the discovery app but still not in airprint.

Comment: Wish I could help further, but from far away it is difficult to be of service   you are halfway there so you need to find some tests that isolate what is going on.  It could be a lot of things.  Try to find a way to connect from you iphone safari to the printer management.  This sounds like it could be a  mCast issue.  Could be wifi routing, apple wifi  network security, need to approach it systematically and isolate functionality. Do you have a Mac  that you could do some testing with?

Comment: Ok, thanks. Something crossed mind though, do i need pfSense?

Comment: If you do, it should not be because of this problem.   If you can't troubleshoot this issue, managing pFsense will be orders of magnitude more complicated.  The reason I linked that article was because the Airprint info stood on its own without needing to worry about the pFsense related content.